# Rearranging elements of an environment

Tags: macros, environments

I want to create a set of entries where their exact layout will be determined by the environment. I.e.

```
\begin{Animals}
\Animal{Rat}{Mammals}
\Animal{Turtle}{Reptilia}
\Animal{Anaconda}{Reptilia}
\Animal{Whale}{Mammals}
\end{Animals}
```

which depending on how 'Animals' environment is defined can be expanded to

```
Animal   | Class
-------------------
Rat      | Mammals
Turtle   | Reptilia
Anaconda | Reptilia
Whale    | Mammals
```

or to

```
Mammals
  * Rat
  * Whale
Reptilia
  * Anaconda
  * Turtle
```

While creating an environment of the first type seems relatively straightforward, the second one seems cryptic to me. Any suggestions, or direction to some documentation/sources/books is highly appreciated. Or maybe I've chosen the wrong tool for the task (of laying out data entries) and it shouldn't be done with environments at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is something like a hash and using `expl3` features can simplify this

Answer (score 5):

This uses separate lists for each animal category, e.g. mammals, birds, fish etc and a global list that has all categories stored with `\Animal`.

The `\DisplayAnimals` macro loops through the various categories and calls a local macro that displays the individual animals for that category, however, unsorted.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\seq_new:N \g_oytis_allcategories_seq


\NewDocumentCommand{\Animal}{+mm}{%
  \seq_if_exist:cF {g_oytis_#2_seq} {%
    \seq_new:c {g_oytis_#2_seq}
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_oytis_allcategories_seq {#2}
  }
  \seq_gput_right:cn {g_oytis_#2_seq}{#1}
  \seq_remove_duplicates:c {g_oytis_#2_seq}
}




\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplayAnimalCategory}{m}{%
  \seq_if_empty:cF {g_oytis_#1_seq} {
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      #1 & \tabularnewline
      \seq_map_inline:cn {g_oytis_#1_seq} { & ##1 \tabularnewline}
    \end{tabular}
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplayAnimals}{}{%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_oytis_allcategories_seq {
    \DisplayAnimalCategory{##1}
    \par
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff  

\begin{document}

\Animal{cat}{Mammals}

\Animal{dog}{Mammals}

\Animal{snake}{Reptilia}


\Animal{cow}{Mammals}

\Animal{tuna}{Fish}

\DisplayAnimals

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A better setup depends on more information, of course

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach using lists from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. The idea is to make `\Animal` add the data to several internal lists -- one for the list of animals, one for the list of categories and one for the animals in a given category. To print the animals/categories we then loop over these lists using `\dolistloop`.

In the spirit of the question I have wrapped everything inside an `Animals` environment that takes an optional argument. Without the optional argument the table of animals and categories is printed. If *anything* is given as an optional argument then the list of categories is printed as a `description` environment. You could tighten this up so that the optional argument is more tightly specified.

In practice, it is not necessary to use the `Animals` environment and, instead, the `\Animal` commands can be given anywhere after which `\PrintAnimalTable` and `\PrintAnimalsByCategory` can be used to print the data. On the other hand, as the MWE below shows, one "feature" of this approach is that the `\Animal` commands are "local" to the `Animals` environment so that different `Animals` environments can be used independently of each other in the document. (`\Animal` commands used outside of an environmen (any environment), will be "global".)

The output of the MWE below is:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\animals{}
\newcommand\categories{}
\newcommand\Animal[2]{%
  % list of animals 
  \ifinlist{#1}\animals{}{\listadd\animals{#1&#2}}%
  % list of categories
  \ifinlist{#2}{\categories}{}{\listadd\categories{#2}}%
  % list of animals in category
  \ifinlistcs{#1}{cat-#2}{}{\listcsadd{cat-#2}{#1}}%
}
\newcommand\PrintAnimalsByCategory{%
   \renewcommand*\do[1]{\item[##1]% define \do to print itemized list
     \begin{itemize}
       \item[]
       \forlistcsloop{\item}{cat-##1}
     \end{itemize}
   }%
   \begin{description}
     \dolistloop{\categories}
   \end{description}%
}
\newcommand\PrintAnimalTable{%
   \renewcommand*\do[1]{##1\\}% define do to print line in tabular
   \begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
     Animal & Category\\ \midrule
     \dolistloop{\animals}
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
}
\NewEnviron{Animals}[1][]
{\BODY% environment assumed to just contain \Animal commands,
  % so we process these
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax% print table by default
    \PrintAnimalTable%
  \else%
    \PrintAnimalsByCategory%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{Animals}
    \Animal{Rat}{Mammals}
    \Animal{Turtle}{Reptilia}
    \Animal{Anaconda}{Reptilia}
    \Animal{Whale}{Mammals}
    \Animal{Albatross}{Bird}
  \end{Animals}

  \begin{Animals}[categories]
    \Animal{Rat}{Mammals}
    \Animal{Turtle}{Reptilia}
    \Animal{Anaconda}{Reptilia}
    \Animal{Whale}{Mammals}
  \end{Animals}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Here is a translation of the code above into [expl3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) with the additional feature that the lists are now sorted alphabetically (I don't know how to sort lists without `expl3`). Here is the new output:

[image]

and here is the new code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\animals{}
\newcommand\categories{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_animals_seq    % list of animals
\seq_new:N \l_categories_seq % list of categories
\newcommand\Animal[2]{%
  % list of animals
  \seq_if_in:NnF \l_animals_seq {#1} { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_animals_seq {#1&#2}}
  % list of categories
  \seq_if_in:NnF \l_categories_seq {#2} { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_categories_seq {#2}}
  % list of animals in category
  \seq_if_exist:cTF {l_category_#2_seq}
    {  \seq_if_in:cnF {l_category_#2_seq} {#1}
                      { \seq_put_right:cn {l_category_#2_seq} {#1}}
    }{ \seq_new:c {l_category_#2_seq}
       \seq_put_right:cn {l_category_#2_seq} {#1}
    }
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \l_sort_sequence:N #1 {
  \seq_sort:Nn #1 {
    \int_compare:nTF { \pdftex_strcmp:D { ##1 } { ##2 } < 0 }
                     {\sort_return_same:}
                     {\sort_return_swapped:}
   }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \l_sort_sequence:N { c }

\newcommand\PrintAnimalsByCategory{%
   \begin{description}
     \l_sort_sequence:N \l_categories_seq
     \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_categories_seq {
       \item[##1]% print itemized list
       \begin{itemize}
         \item[]\item
         \l_sort_sequence:c {l_category_##1_seq}
         \seq_use:cn {l_category_##1_seq} {\item}
       \end{itemize}
     }
   \end{description}%
}
\newcommand\PrintAnimalTable{%
   \begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
     Animal & Category\\ \midrule
     \l_sort_sequence:N \l_animals_seq
     \seq_use:Nn \l_animals_seq { \\}
     \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewEnviron{Animals}[1][]
{\BODY% environment assumed to just contain \Animal commands,
  % so we process these
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax% print table by default
    \PrintAnimalTable%
  \else%
    \PrintAnimalsByCategory%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{Animals}
    \Animal{Rat}{Mammals}
    \Animal{Turtle}{Reptilia}
    \Animal{Anaconda}{Reptilia}
    \Animal{Whale}{Mammals}
    \Animal{Albatross}{Bird}
  \end{Animals}

  \begin{Animals}[categories]
    \Animal{Rat}{Mammals}
    \Animal{Turtle}{Reptilia}
    \Animal{Anaconda}{Reptilia}
    \Animal{Whale}{Mammals}
  \end{Animals}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution which uses only TeX primitives:

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\listca{} \def\listan{}
\def\Animal#1#2{\expandafter\ifx\csname ca:#2\endcsname\relax
   \sdef{ca:#2}{#1,}\addto\listca{#2,}%
   \else \expandafter\addto\csname ca:#2\endcsname{#1,}%
   \fi
   \addto\listan{#1:#2,}%
}
\def\taban #1:#2,{\ifx:#1:\else \firstfi #1:#2,\fi}
\def\firstfi#1:#2,\fi{\fi #1&#2\cr\taban}

\def\tabrule{\noalign{\medskip\hrule\medskip}}
\def\printanimals{\halign{\ ##\unskip\hfil&\quad##\unskip\hfil\ \cr \tabrule
   Animal & Category \cr \tabrule
   \expandafter \taban \listan:,\crcr \tabrule}
}
\def\printca#1,{\ifx,#1,\else 
   \par\noindent{\bf #1}\par
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\printcaB\csname ca:#1\endcsname,%
   \expandafter\printca\fi
}
\def\printcaB#1,{\ifx,#1,\else\par\indent\llap{$\bullet$ }#1\par
   \expandafter\printcaB\fi
}
\def\printcategories{\expandafter\printca\listca,}

\Animal{Albatross}{Bird}
\Animal{Anaconda}{Reptilia}
\Animal{Rat}{Mammals}
\Animal{Turtle}{Reptilia}
\Animal{Whale}{Mammals}

\printanimals

\bigskip
\printcategories

\end
```